# Is this sql statement vulnerable?

Tags: sql, database, sql-injection

I just took over management for a webservice and today i got a user report about this error. Now i'm no sql injection expert but does this error make this attack possible?

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-4.1.22-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '') ORDER BY TCOL_date desc' at line 1
```

I'm asking because for some reason i'm not given access to the code and the previous guy insists that the site is safe so i need to come with some proof or facts that it's actually vulnerable.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nope, this error means, **theres an error in the sql?** We will have to see the query, and how it is buil, etc. to tell if there are any issues here.

Comment: If you get error messages about fragments of SQL, it is quite possible that someone managed to cut off a command and insert their own command in the middle.  It depends on whether middleware submits user generated text as part of a command or using a placeholder like ?.  Placeholders are supposed to be escaped by the API to avoid an attack.  Using user generated text as part of an SQL command is unsafe.

Comment: Like i mentioned i'm just doing support/management, i wasn't given access to the code so i can't view the query so this is all i have to go by. I could reproduce it by putting a ' in a search field on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short Not really... but.**

While this might provide more information than you're comfortable with (version of MySQL running, drivers being used, and a little about a couple of columns), it's not going to open you up to an attack as much as showing the whole SQL line would. Someone could try to blind hack it to get more information, and the fact that it's showing any info at all is a lot worse for you from the standpoint of an attacker trying to get in than showing info only in the logs. Feedback, even a little can aid an attack[er].

If by trying to insert various bits of code into the form you can get a response that prints your own content you're inserting this would be much more beneficial to an attacker. The fact that this application breaks when you insert a `'` leads me to believe that it's not as *secure* as the programmer claims. This might also lead an attacker to look for another avenue of attack. If they can insert javascript code into a form and have it display in a profile, or if they can inject code that's executed upon return from the server, then they could exploit the server and use it to launch their own attacks.

The problems with SQL injection come back to [code] implementation and the types of things allowed (and blindly processed) by the forms. For instance if you could escape a single quote `\'` in your current situation, someone could open and close the SQL statement and possibly `UNION` their own statement when pulling a query. If they could close the statement and append another statement, they might add `delete from users where 1=1` or something of that nature. Another way might be if you can type in `<marquee>Test</marquee>` and it prints the word "test" scrolling when it finds no results then you can perform injections because it's not stripping out code.

This all leads back to permissions. The permissions on the server should make it so the users on the front end of the site only have access to the permission levels they need. If they're only querying the database (`SELECT`), they should not have access to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DROP TABLES`, or `DELETE`.

Comment: Right, i'm gonna report the unwanted information disclosure at least but you are saying it's not vulnerable to an injection? I'm again no expert so i just tested a few examples, if i enter `or 'a' = 'a` into the search field with the issue i get `syntax to use near 'a' = 'a%') ORDER BY TCOL_date desc`. I'm not sure if thats helpful to decide anything.

Comment: Try to insert `'a%' = 'a`. I'm not saying it's not vulnerable to SQL injection at all. I'm saying with this snippet of code it's not really telling you one way or another. Here are some real world examples of injection attacks. http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: Right, thanks for clarifying. Also inserting that gave me `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a%' = 'a%') ORDER BY TCOL_date desc`

Comment: It looks like he's using a like statement. The code you're inserting into is surrounded by single quotes. You can try this `' UNION select * from users where 'a%'='a`. If it's a select query and it's returning the same number of columns, then it might give a list of usernames. Because `'a%'='a%'` will always return true.

Comment: this gave me `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION select * from users where 'a%'='a%') ORDER BY TRAD_datum desc' at line 1` but yeah, i'll give set your answer as correct after this but if you got any further ideas please comment :)